# Angular - Number input first digit should be Zero

Tags: angular

I've a Number input field which takes Mobile number. I want to make it mandatory for the user to enter first digit as '0' (zero).
Should I use some regex pattern or just find the first digit and if NOT zero then print some message?
I'm not a developer so also how to find the first digit in Angular. I found ways in JavaScript but not particularly for Angular.

Answer (score 0):

you could create a pattern using a regular expression, then use that pattern in the template.  e.g.

```
mobileNumPattern = 'yourRegExHere';
```

Then in the HTML template you can use this:

```
<input name="mobileNum" [pattern]="mobileNumPattern"> </input>+
```

you can read the docs here https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use custom directive for your own requirements,

Here is custom Phone Mask Directive for you,

```
import { Directive, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[formControlName][appPhoneMask]',
})
export class PhoneMaskDirective {

  constructor(public ngControl: NgControl) { }

  @HostListener('ngModelChange', ['$event'])
  onModelChange(event) {
    this.onInputChange(event, false);
  }

  @HostListener('keydown.backspace', ['$event'])
  keydownBackspace(event) {
    this.onInputChange(event.target.value, true);
  }


  onInputChange(event, backspace) {
    let newVal = event.replace(/\D/g, '');
    if (backspace && newVal.length <= 6) {
      newVal = newVal.substring(0, newVal.length - 1);
    }
    if (newVal.length === 0) {
      newVal = '';
    } else if (newVal.length <= 3) {
      newVal = newVal.replace(/^(\d{0,3})/, '($1)');
    } else if (newVal.length <= 6) {
      newVal = newVal.replace(/^(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})/, '($1) ($2)');
    } else if (newVal.length <= 10) {
      newVal = newVal.replace(/^(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/, '($1) ($2)-$3');
    } else {
      newVal = newVal.substring(0, 10);
      newVal = newVal.replace(/^(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/, '($1) ($2)-$3');
    }
    this.ngControl.valueAccessor.writeValue(newVal);
  }
}
```

Stackblitz repo link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-phone-mask-mu7hsx